# couldn't find tensorflow version

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working with python3.7 and trying to download Tensor flow library but it gives me following error

*ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow*

I am using pip installation as:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

I have tried many methods but I always gets the same error.

Comment: Can you inform if you are using pip installation or how you are downloading and which code you are trying to execute

Comment: i am using pip installation

Comment: try to use `pip3 install tensorflow` if you are not updated your environment before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm that you are using the 64bit version of python as this is a requirement for tensorflow:

Check your python with:

```
python-32 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
('7fffffff', False)

python-64 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
('7fffffffffffffff', True)
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion, I was using python 32 bit that's why I was having that issue

Answer (score 1):

Try conda install if you are using Anaconda.
Go to your anaconda prompt by searching same in windows search. After Opening Anaconda prompt, try this command **conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow**

Hope error wont come now.